# Problem with WooCommerce OrderRefund using the C# Rest API

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

When using the C# Rest API from WooCommerce to retrieve a Order refund and using the following statement:

```
OrderRefund orderRefund =  await wc.Order.Refunds.Get(2621, 1869);

Running: Net-Framework 4.7.2, 
WordPress 5.3, 
WooCommerce 3.8.0,
WooCommerceNET 0.8.0, 
WordPressPCL 1.6.2
```

I get the error message:

> An error occured when re-serializing the object of type WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.OrderRefund. The value cannot be of the type Int32. The order refund 2621 for order 1869 exists.

When trying to retrieve a non existing refund, i.e. 2622, it just works fine and returns me an empty object, which is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Errors pretty clear on whats wrong here

WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.OrderRefund. The value **cannot be of the type Int32**. **The order refund 2621 for order 1869 exists.**

So your using Woocom.net Wrapper

(int id, int parentId) Theres the expected Value So The Int32 Error is a bit of a miss here, But I'm confused your trying to refund a order that already has a refund request. Is this Intended?

Also have a look at this

https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET/issues/78

The Topic has been Resolved on the Repository

https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET/issues/159

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15124